# Power Bi Json Theme - Pivot Table Grand Totals Not Returning Color Choices

Tags: json, powerbi

I'm trying to use a Power bi Json theme and can't seem to get the grand totals to change the grand totals background color and font color. And not only that, but it is also choosing a black background color which is no-where in my Json at all and looks terrible.

Another thing to note, it is not a global setting above as if I do not include the 'pivotTable' in my Json, there is no black background anymore. It also seems the font for the grand totals is taken from the subtotals category and nothing from the 'totals' section. I've tried changing the name to the following without any luck as well: ('total', 'grandTotal', 'rowTotal', 'columnTotal', 'grandTotals', 'rowgrandTotals', columngrandTotals' etc.)

Below is the current Json I have for the pivot table followed by an image of what it produced:

```
"pivotTable": {
            "*": {
                "stylePreset":[{
                 "name":"Condensed"
                            }],
                    "grid": [{
                    "gridVertical": true,
                    "gridVerticalColor": { "solid": { "color": "#E6E6E6"}},
                    "gridVerticalWeight": 1,
                    "gridHorizontal": true,
                    "gridHorizontalColor": { "solid": { "color": "#E6E6E6"}},
                    "gridHorizontalWeight": 1,
                    "rowPadding": 1,
                    "outlineColor": { "solid": { "color": "#E6E6E6"}},
                    "outlineWeight": 1,
                    "textSize": 10,
                    "imageHeight": 100
                }],
                "columnHeaders": [{
                    "fontColor": { "solid": { "color": "#454545"}},
                    "backColor": { "solid": { "color": "#F6F8FC"}},
                    "outline": "Frame",
                    "autoSizeColumnWidth": true,
                    "fontFamily": "Arial",
                    "fontSize": 10,
                    "alignment": "Left",
                    "titleAlignment": "Right",
                    "urlIcon": true,
                    "wordWrap": true
                }],
                "rowHeaders": [{
                    "fontColor": { "solid": { "color": "#454545"}},
                    "backColor": { "solid": { "color": "#FFFFFF"}},
                    "outline": "Frame",
                    "stepped": true,
                    "steppedLayoutIndentation": 12,                 
                    "urlIcon": true,
                    "wordWrap": true,
                    "fontFamily": "Arial",
                    "fontSize": 10,
                    "alignment": "Left", 
                    "showExpandCollapseButtons":true
                }],
                "values": [{
                    "fontColorPrimary": { "solid": { "color": "#454545"}},
                    "backColorPrimary": { "solid": { "color": "#FFFFFF"}},
                    "fontColorSecondary": { "solid": { "color": "#454545"}},
                    "backColorSecondary": { "solid": { "color": "#FFFFFF"}},
                    "bandedRowHeaders": true,
                    "valuesOnRow": false,
                    "outline": "Frame",
                    "urlIcon": true,
                    "wordWrap": true,
                    "fontFamily": "Arial",
                    "fontSize": 9
                }],
                "subTotals": [{
                    "rowSubtotals": true,
                    "columnSubtotals": true,
                    "fontColor": { "solid": { "color": "#454545"}},
                    "fontFamily": "Arial",
                    "backColor": { "solid": { "color": "#FFFFFF"}},
                    "fontSize": 10,
                    "applyToHeaders": true,
                    "rowSubtotalsPosition": "Bottom",
                    "perRowLevel": true,
                    "perColumnLevel": true                  
                }],             
                "totals": [{
                    "fontColor": { "solid": { "color": "#454545"}},
                    "fontFamily": "Arial",
                    "backColor": { "solid": { "color": "#FFFFFF"}},
                    "applyToHeaders": true,
                    "fontSize": 10
                }]
                
            }
        }
```

[image]

Expecting the Theme to have the color format listed in the 'totals' section of the Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to add "rowTotal" and "columnTotal" like

```json
"rowTotal": [
  {
    "fontColor": {
      "solid": {
        "color": "#000000"
      }
    },
    "fontFamily": "Segoe UI",
    "backColor": {
      "solid": {
        "color": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "applyToHeaders": true,
    "outline": "Frame",
    "fontSize": 10
  }
],
"columnTotal": [
  {
    "fontColor": {
      "solid": {
        "color": "#000000"
      }
    },
    "fontFamily": "Segoe UI",
    "backColor": {
      "solid": {
        "color": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "applyToHeaders": true,
    "outline": "Frame",
    "fontSize": 10
  }
]
```

Comment: Wow I thought I tried that and got nothing before. But I tried it and it worked, thanks. Must have had something slightly off.